# Android play sound without lag

Tags: android, audio

I want to play a horn sound in the app without any lag. I am using Media player class but its giving lag while playing file again.

code to run:

thread to improve the lag:(mp_horn is the media player instance we made from sound file) Below thread gives us much better result then making mediaplayer.setloop(true)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (mp_horn != null && mp_horn.isPlaying()) {

            final long durationTotal_horn = mp_horn
                    .getDuration();
            long durationCurrent_horn = mp_horn
                    .getCurrentPosition();
            if (durationCurrent_horn >= (.90) * durationTotal_horn) {
                // mp_engineContiue.seekTo((int)
                // durationCurrent_back);

                Log.v("arrrrrr", durationCurrent_horn
                        + "......."
                        + durationTotal_horn);
                // mp_engineContiue.pause();
                mp_horn.seekTo((int) (durationTotal_horn * .0000001));

            }

        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
if (mp_horn != null && mp_horn.isPlaying())
```

should be :

```
if (mp_horn != null && !mp_horn.isPlaying())
```

otherwise while the Horn is playing you are doing all these calculations all over again, which I am guessing is causing the lag

Comment: Have you tried using an ASyncTask to play the sound?